# Windows 10: Enable network browsing / WS-Discovery / UPnP / SSDP service discovery across subnets from Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, discovery, explorer, upnp, ssdp

I have the following scenario: Two sites, each with their own network (non-overlapping private subnet), connected with a site-to-site VPN (layer 3, Wireguard). Routes to the other sites are configured in the default gateways and also distributed to the clients over DHCP. IP traffic (v4 and v6) travels fine between the networks.

On both VPN gateways, [avahi-daemon](https://www.avahi.org/) works as mDNS repeater (`enable-reflector=yes`) between the local network and the wireguard tunnel, and [smcroute](https://github.com/troglobit/smcroute) is set up to forward [routable SSDP multicast packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol#Protocol_transport_and_addressing) (sent to `239.255.255.250`, `ff05::c`, `ff08::c`) from the local network to the wireguard tunnel and vice versa. This works well, both MDNS and SSDP packets travel from one network to the other, I checked it with Wireshark.

On Windows 10 (21H2), mDNS name resolution of .local Domains works well across both networks, thanks to avahi-daemon reflection. In VLC on Windows, multimedia devices from both networks are found with mDNS as well as UPnP (SSDP) and can be accessed. However, the Windows Explorer only shows devices from the local network in its Network view.

I checked and tried the following things already:

- The Function Discovery Resource Publication service (FDResPub) is enabled and running.
- The Function Discovery Provider Host service (fdPHost) is enabled and running (although to my understanding this is not necessary for service discovery).
- Network discovery and file and printer sharing are both turned on for the active network profile (Private) in advanced sharing settings.
- I completely disabled Windows firefall for testing (no other firewall products installed).

When hitting Ctrl+F5 in the Network view in Windows Explorer, I can see SSDP M-SEARCH requests being sent to the multicast addresses `239.255.255.250` and `ff02::c`. The IPv6 address `ff02::c` is a link-local multicast address and is not routed to the other network, but the request sent to `239.255.255.250` does reach the other network and answers from devices there reach the local network. But these devices are not displayed in Windows Explorer.

I found the [documentation of Windows UPnP APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/upnp/universal-plug-and-play-start-page). There is a section about [configuration settings](http://Configuration%20Settings) that can be changed with registry keys. Most of the mentioned registry-paths exist, but none of the mentioned keys are set. The keys `DownloadScope` and `ReceiveScope` both default to `1`, which allows discovery of hosts in private subnets. I also added both keys to the registry (as DWORD 32-bit), explicitly set them to 1 and rebooted the Windows machine, but Windows Explorer still only shows other computers from the same subnet.

The [UPnPDeviceFinder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/upnp/creating-the-device-finder) can be used from a PowerShell to list UPnP devices ([credits](https://help.lametric.com/support/discussions/topics/6000042957)):

```
$ssdpFinder = New-Object -ComObject 'UPnP.UPnPDeviceFinder'
$ssdpFinder.FindByType('ssdp:all', 0)
```

This *does* find UPnP devices from both local and remote network, also with `DownloadScope` and `ReceiveScope` unspecified in the registry. However, the IPv6 SSDP M-SEARCH requests are sent to `ff02::c` even with `DownloadScope` and `ReceiveScope` both explicitly set to `1` and thus [shall not be routed to other networks](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-multicast-addresses/ipv6-multicast-addresses.xhtml#link-local).

So two questions remain:

- How can Windows 10 be configured so that Windows Explorer shows devices from other networks discovered over WS-Discovery / UPnP / SSDP in the Network view?
- How can Windows 10 (UPnPDeviceFinder, Windows Explorer) be configured to broadcast IPv6 SSDP M-SEARCH requests to `ff05::c` or `ff08::c` instead of `ff02::c`, so that the multicast messages may be routed to other networks?